# finding product UUID on Linux works on CLI, but not in PHP

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface

when I run this command (as root) from the linux command line:

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid
```

I get the UUID of the machine just fine.  But when I do this in php:

```
echo `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid`;
```

I am not getting an output.  An  in PHP reveals that I am `www-data` which is what I would have expected.

The obvious question: Why no output?  and if it is a permission issue, would there be a way to put that command in a shell script and call it via PHP that way?  thanks.

**UPDATE:** I believe this was a permission issue.  when changing the permissions to the product_uuid file from r-- --- --- for root:root to r-- --- r--, I can read the file via PHP, but would much rather call a shell script as www-data that could get the file contents.

Comment: What are you using uuid for? Are you aware that it can easily be spoofed and is not a safe way to determine uniqueness of computers?

Comment: That was not my question, guess I'll wait for an answer from someone else.  The answer to your question is, it is being used to determine the identity of 5-6 computers in a secured group of programmers to then figure out where the db is we want to connect to.  We're all in the same group and all of this information is internal for each computer.  I'm not worried about it being spoofed in this case.

Comment: Aha, fair enough. Just wanted to make sure you were aware. You should know however that *some* computers do not return an actual `uuid` when queried for it, since the network device doesn't return one. On the otherhand in response to your question, are the php script and the command line entries being run by the same user?

Comment: Does it work if you do `$output = \`cat ...\`; echo $output;`, as in the docs? And do other commands work? Does `echo \`ls -la\`` work?

Comment: I am pretty sure I edited after you made this last comment @will, bottom line it was a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be use `exec` function in php

```
echo exec('cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid');
```

Answer (score 0):

please use `shell_exec()` function to get the output

```
echo shell_exec('/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/product_uuid');
```

this will display the output as string